# how to add to an rsynced tar backup

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I see several places that describe how to create an rsynced tar backup, ie:

```
GZIP='--rsyncable' tar cvzf bobsbackup.tar.gz /whatever
```

or

```
tar -c /whatever | gzip --rsyncable > file.tar.gz
```

Very good. However, after I add or edit files in the /whatever directory, how do I update the compressed tar backup?

Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You invoke rsync on the archive just created with one of the commands above:

```
rsync -av archive.tar.gz /mnt/my-external-harddrive/archive.tar.gz
```

The last parameter may vary depending on your setup, e.g. it could also be a file on a remote machine that you access via ssh etc.

Comment: Can you give me a complete example? I think what you mean is that rsync will identify new/updated files, but will add them to the backup, not update the files already existing in the backup. Thanks.

Comment: That is great. Thanks very much.